Magento 2.2.5 imported files and database on server don't deploy correctly
recently a shop gave me the full directory and database of a site in magento. I've uploaded it on a new server on plesk and changed server domain. The problem is that after i deployed all of the static files i can't edit a product cause it's stuck on loading. inspecting with browser it's giving error 404 on some js components that are not present in static folder. Anyone know the correct way to import a server and use the static files already in pub folder?


Few thing you have to verify
First: please make sure you have deploy the code properly.
For Example:
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f 
php bin/magento c:f

Second: Make sure pub/static/.htaccess is not deleted
(U see there is issue says "Refuse to ex.." that is cros issue either you can disable it (not recommented) or you can resolve it with standard way using .xml in etc folder)
Thanks

i've tried but when i compile it gives me this error:
Fatal error:  Interface 'Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface' not found in public_html/vendor/mageplaza/module-smtp/Model/Resolver/Bestsellers/Bestsellers.php on line 47

Try Removing Mageplaza SMTP extension
